# akka sample Hello! gives error on receive method

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt, akka

I will not paste the code here, I simply have this:

https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-samples/akka-sample-hello/src/main/scala/sample/hello/Main.scala

And I wonder why Eclipse gives error on

```
def receive
```

saying:

> type mismatch; found : Any => Unit required: akka.actor.Actor.Receive
>   (which expands to) PartialFunction[Any,Unit]

I suppose it's something about the fact that there are some "case" statements inside a block without a "match" in front.

How can I remove the error, or how can I make eclipse runnning well with Akka?

Comment: The code in the example looks fine.  You positive it's an Eclipse problem?  You also positive the code is exactly the same as that example?

Comment: I ensure you is the same, I've just copy pasted, and i've substituted these ⇒ with these =>. Ran with sbt, it compiles fine. If of any importance, scala version is 2.11.0; I think anyway that the problem is in eclipse having somehow problems with akka

Comment: Which `receive` is throwing the error?

Comment: What version of Akka are you using. I was not aware that there is a version that works on Scala 2.11

Comment: Eclipse classpath may be wrong....

Comment: The case statements are certainly not an issue. That's what many partial functions look like.

Comment: How should I set classpaths? I have only included the Akka library in the build path.
I'm using Akka 2.2.1
both receive are throwing the same error

Comment: If you don't paste the actual code you are using and include the versions of Eclipse and the ScalaIDE plugin then we won't be able to help you.

Comment: The code is exactly as you see in the link, I didn't change anything, neither imports (3). I'm using Eclipse Kepler and Scala 2.11.0